# Load dynamically a ResourceDictionnary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, xamlreader

I'm having some issues. I want my app to load a ResourceDictonnary dynamically in app.xaml.cs.

This is my code for the moment :

```
ResourceDictionary theme = XamlReader.Load(???);
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(theme);
```

The problem is, how can I get my ResourceDictionnary stream from the xaml file ? I don't want to copy the xaml file with the exe. It's build action is set to Page and I want to load it.

Can you tell me how to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the following code (I call it from my IModule.Initialize)

```
 Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
            .Add(new ResourceDictionary
            {
                Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/My.Application;component/Resources/Resources.xaml")
            });
```

see the project tree in attached image:
[image: project tree in VS]

Comment: Documentation for the Uri syntax is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx